# Function gives input number * the lenght of array instead of input number * array values (javascript)

Tags: javascript

If I use number 5 as input, I want my function to return 5*4*3*2*1.
The problem is that my for each loop returns 5 * 5, meaning the input multiplied with the length of my array instead of the input multiplied with the values of the array (wich should be 4, 3, 2, 1).

```
function FirstFactorial(num) {
var a = 1;
var numbers = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < num; i++){
    numbers[i] = a;
    a++;
}

for (integer in numbers){
    factor = num * numbers[integer];
}    
return factor;    
}   

FirstFactorial(5);       
//EXPECTED OUTPUT: 5*4*3*2*1 = 120
```

Comment: You're multiplying each number by your function parameter, and overwriting `factor` in each iteration. You probably meant to declare `var factor = 1` before the loop and then inside the loop do `factor *= numbers[integer]`

Comment: for fun, an ES6 way also using an array:
   `function fact(n) {`
      `return [...Array(n).keys()].reduce((p,c) => p * (c+1),1)`
    `}`

Answer (score -1):

make like that

```
function FirstFactorial(num){
   var result = 1;
   while(num > 0){
     result = num*result;
     num--;
   }
 return result;
}
```

Comment: This gave me no output.

Comment: @ApoLLoSkiLLz This code seemed to work fine for me. Did you get any errors? If so, please post them. [link](http://puu.sh/qQxEt.png)

Comment: Oops! I forgot to call my function. You code works perfect.